# Switching role between fork and parent

Tags: github

I've assumed maintainership for a given project on github. I've done so by cloning the repository of the original authors and pushing my own changes and developments. This was done in accord with the original authors, so they do not expect to work on this in the future. Nevertheless, my repository is marked as a fork of theirs, which makes it appear less official. Is there some way to denote a given repository as official? To swap the relation between my repository and that of the original developers?

I guess I could delete my repository, then ask the original devs to transfer theirs to mine, then let the original devs fork from that, then push my own changes from my local repo. But somehow this feels wrong. It would rely on my local copy. Migration of e.g. the pages branch might be causing extra trouble. I hope there is a cleaner solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There doesn't seem to be a clean way to do this.

It seems your best option is to ask GitHub support to convert your repository to "normal mode" as opposed to "forked from" mode.

Another solution is to delete and recreate the repository. However, this can be dangerous, as the wiki and issues data will also be deleted in this process.

If you have further questions about this then let me know in comments and I can amend my answer.