# Github switching fork parent

Tags: git, github, git-fork

See the relating question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17491853/switching-role-between-fork-and-parent).

The scenario described there is saying that he wanted to take ownership of a project and  convert his forked repo into a "normal" node, and the answer suggested that this can only be done by requesting Github support.

The further problem of this is, if I was forked the project's original fork master (since that one is the "official" one), and later I was noticed that a new guy is now owning the project and I need to switch to his repo, rather than my original one. So what should I do?

I know I can simply add more "remote"s in git but my pull requests will need to sent to the new repo, not the old one, so this is not a solution.

Answer (score 2):

You could simply create a [new fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6286877/6309): a fork of the new official repo, and:

- report your commits from your old fork to the new fork (in a dedicated branch),
- rebase that branch on top of the fork master branch,
- the make a PR from the new fork dedicated branch to the new official repo.

The idea of the rebase step is to make sure your PR will apply easily on top of the most recent commit of the master branch of the new official repo.